# How to return an error with detailed error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I use the following code in an ASP.NET Core project to return a detailed error message (business logic related errors):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PoolStatic>> Get(string id)
{
    if (id== null)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("id is not provided."),
            ReasonPhrase = "id not found"
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }
 ....
```

However, the client gets `HTTP 500` and the raw response message doesn't contain the message I set:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2016 02:19:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Kestrel
```

Comment: why are you throwing instead of returning the message?

Comment: @mason I followed an example. It returns 500 though

Comment: @DanielA.White I read the code from asp.net website. The example throws an exception?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to ensure that it runs as expected? Go line by line, make sure your custom `HttpResponseException` is being thrown? The error you're showing makes it look like something may have errored out beforehand. Also, I usually use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` rather than just comparing strings to null.

Comment: @mason Yes, the line `throw new HttpResponseException(resp);` was last run.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit I have little experience with ASP.NET Core. But it looks like you're using the Web API Compatibility Shim. I cloned the MVC repo and by checking where `HttpResponseException` was referenced I saw [this ActionFilter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/HttpResponseExceptionActionFilter.cs). It may be registered by default, but just try registering that to see if it processes correctly. Or temporarily put MVC into your project instead of referencing via NuGet so you can debug the framework code and see if it's behaving.

Comment: Judging by [this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/) you need to do some setup for the compatibility shim to work. Do you have `services.AddWebApiConventions();` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, a better way to achieve this behavior would be to return a `Task<IActionResult>` from the controller, which lets you do this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    if (id== null)
    {
        return BadRequest("id is not provided.");
    }

    // other code, including:
    // return Ok(some data);
}
```

`BadRequest()` is a helper method that creates a [BadRequestObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestobjectresult#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_BadRequestObjectResult), and sends a `400 Bad Request` response back to the client with whatever data you provide.